# Excel Table Formula References change on Power Query Data Refresh

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-tables

I can't seem to find any solutions when searching Google or Youtube.

I have an Excel workbook with tables linked to SQL stored procedures via Microsoft Query connections. I've added columns to the tables that contain formulas referencing a 'Sales' column.

Every time I refresh my data (Data > Refresh All) my formula references change. See examples below:

Formula before refresh:

```
IF(AF9=Dates!$F$3,'SQL - SellIn Data'!AH9,IF(Dates!$A$18=Dates!$A$21,'SQL - SellIn Data'!AH9,('SQL - SellIn Data'!AH9/Dates!$A$27)*Dates!$A$24))
```

Formula after refresh:

```
IF(AF9=Dates!$F$3,'SQL - SellIn Data'!AH18,IF(Dates!$A$18=Dates!$A$21,'SQL - SellIn Data'!AH18,('SQL - SellIn Data'!AH18/Dates!$A$27)*Dates!$A$24))
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the External Data Properties settings and choose the option to "Overwrite existing cells with new data, clear unused cells". This setting should fix the issue. The other options would insert and delete rows during data refresh, causing Excel to shift cell references that span across the inserted/deleted rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
'SQL - SellIn Data'!$AH$9
```

check also your settings...

[image: external data properties]

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Absolute referencing the cell gets reverted still upon refresh. Regarding my settings, what exactly am I checking please?

Comment: @Maulesi62 normally, when you dont change any structure of the query or pivot etc , this shouldnt happen or at least happens one time only. you can choose & try "Overwrite existing cells" so it will not insert the new data but be careful if there are any other cells filled around it...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a formula that would change after a query modification

from
StatsTable!AB:AB
to
StatsTable!AK:AK

Setting the Overwrite option, as described above, didn't work for me. I tried other ways, like using named range, but to no avail.

The only thing that worked was to isolate the reference as a string in an indirect call like this:

INDIRECT("StatsTable!AB:AB")